# The edge module has not been pre-compiled for node.js version v6.3.0

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2015, multi-device-hybrid-apps

When I try to build my app from `vs2015 update3` for ios, I get this error during compile

> The edge module has not been pre-compiled for node.js version v6.3.0. You must build a custom version of edge.node. Please refer to https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge for building instructions

I went to that project on github, but I couldn't find anything usefull.

also I run `sudo npm i edge` on mac and edge compiles fine but still can't build the app

also I cleared the npm cache on mac by `sudo npm clear cache` still build error

My environment on mac is:

- node 6.3.0
- npm 3.10.6
- cordova 5.4.1

My environment on windows

- Win10
- Vs2015 update 3
- node 6.3.0
- npm 3.10.6
- cordova 5.4.1

### Update 1

when I try to install edge by `npm install edge` on windows I get the same error in npm

```
edge@5.9.2 install C:\Users\Reza\node_modules\edge
node tools/install.js
***************************************
Error: The edge module has not been pre-compiled for node.js version v6.3.0. You must build a custom version of edge.node. Please refer to https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge for building instructions.

at determineVersion (C:\Users\Reza\node_modules\edge\lib\edge.js:21:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Reza\node_modules\edge\lib\edge.js:33:102)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Reza\node_modules\edge\tools\checkplatform.js:2:2)
```

---

Success: platform check for edge.js: node.js x64 v6.3.0
C:\Users\Reza
`-- edge@5.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody else has the same problem and saving couple of hours for him/her:

Finally

- downgrade the `node.js` to `v0.12.7` (x86) on `windows` machine, and no change on mac `machine`,
- `clear cordova cahce` in `visual studio`->tools->options->tools for apache cordova

and then it start building fine for ios